# Nesting multiple classes with @import SCSS

Tags: css, sass

How would I nest classes like this in SCSS using @import?

```css
.example.test {
    color: red;
}
```

This can be done in SCSS without the use of @import like this:

```
.example {
    &.test {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

But how would I do it using @import? Let's say we have a file called rules.scss with the following content:

```
.test {
    color: red;
}
```

If I were to do

```
.example {
    @import 'rules.scss';
}
```

Would output

```css
.example .test {
    color: red;
}
```

How would I @import rules.scss with the classes nested together, for example, the follow CSS:

```css
.example.test {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: `.example.test` <-- This is **not** a "nested" rule, it's a single selector for elements with both `.example` _and_ `.test`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT per your edit:

first rename the file `rules.scss` to `_rules.scss` (note the leading underscore)

Then...

```
.example {
    @import "rules";   
}
```

Here is the [SASS/SCSS @import documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import):

Please be aware that @import is in the process of being removed:

> The Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule. Sass
> will gradually phase it out over the next few years, and eventually
> remove it from the language entirely. Prefer the @use rule instead.
> (Note that only Dart Sass currently supports @use. Users of other
> implementations must use the @import rule instead.)

Comment: No, what I mean is you are able to nest stuff like .example { @import 'test.scss'; } and then if there was a rule like .test { color: red; } it will output .example .red { color: red; } but how would I do .example.test instead

Comment: Yes but not with `@import`, see @Cervus' answer

Comment: Edited my question so you are able to understand it better